# Leaflet Legend not showing

Tags: javascript, leaflet, legend

Can someone tell what is wrong with the code? The legend, which is supposed to be the easiest part in not showing up and I cant figure out why. Maybe hidden in some other layer?

Following the getColor and legend code

```js
var legend = L.control({
  position: 'bottomleft'
});

legend.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
    grades = [0.2, 0.26, 0.32, 0.38, 0.44, 0.5, 0.56, 0.62, 0.68, 0.74, 0.8, 0.86, 0.92, 0.98, 1.04, 1.1],
    labels = [],
    from, to;

  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    from = grades[i];
    to = grades[i + 1];

    labels.push(
      '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
      from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
  }

  div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
  return div;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** following answer comments:

Use the developer tools (F12 / on Mac: Cmd + Alt + I) to read potential console errors.

In your case, the `getColor` function is not defined in the scope of your `legend.onAdd`.

Besides, you add `1` to your `from` value, resulting in values ranging in [1.2 - 2.1] whereas your `getColor` function uses values from 0.26 to 1.1.

Working demo using code from your repo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lbKlXaV76t6NclHQPCtr?p=preview (`getColor` copied in correct scope, and removed the `+1` in `getColor(from + 1)`)

---

Original answer:

Did you add your custom control to the map?

```js
legend.addTo(map);
```

As a side note, your `<i>` tag with legend-ed background color from `getColor` does not have any content. Therefore you would probably see no colored content…

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/34/ (with dummy content in your `<i>` tag)

Comment: sorry didnt paste it. legend.addTo(map); was already part of the code along with the getcolor. I copied and paste your code instead on mine and now it doesnt show anything. This all part of a GeoJSON I dont know if that makes a diference

Comment: By the way, did you style your `div.info.legend` legend control container with some background color, in order to see it easily once on the map? Notice I had to apply a white background-color on the above demo.

Comment: Didnt work either :(, it colors and it does it all but showing the legend. Same code, same properties than your code but no legend

Comment: You should include enough code in your question in order for people to be able to reproduce your issue, rather than pointing to your repo. I will update the above answer.

Comment: Sorry my first time using this!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Nice words are always welcome, and the SO way to thank is to **accept** the answer, if it did solve your issue. Once you have enough "reputation", you will also gain the ability to "upvote".

Answer (score 0):

i have similar issue that the width of `i` element is 0 px. 
 try to add a text between `i` and add color to dissapear the text like this:

```
 '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + ';color:' + getColor(from + 1) +';">sometexttogivespace</i> ' +
      from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
```

or copy the css code from leaflet tutorial to set the width of i

```
.legend i {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```